# How to play video automatically for Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, wordpress, magnific-popup

**Hii,**

I am using magnific popup.but I want to play video automatically for
all browsers, when open magnific popup.see I am using this js.

```
function magnificPopupFn() {
    $('.popup-vimeo').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        closeBtnInside: true,
        closeOnBgClick: true,
        callbacks: {
            open: function() {
                $('html').css('margin-right', 0);
                $('body').addClass('noscroll');
                $('iframe').attr('allow', 'autoplay');
            },
            close: function() {
                $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
            }, 
        }
    });
}
magnificPopupFn();
```

Comment: please add your `php` or `html` code used for the above popup

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer possible after "Autoplay Policy Changes", see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes